# How to insert UTF8 literal in GtkTextView?

Tags: python, c, utf-8, gtk

I want to insert `•` into GtkTextView widget. In Python + pyGTK this line was sufficient:

```
self.__textBuffer.insert_at_cursor(u'\u2022')
```

Because I'm rewriting my application to C i need to translate this line of code.

I was trying to do:

```
gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor(textBuffer, "\x20\x22", 2);
```

But it not worked, only inserted 2 chars`"*`.

How can I translate u'\u2022' from Python to C?

Comment: Why not just do gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor(textBuffer, "•", strlen("•"))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to UTF-8 encode it, since GTK+'s encoding is UTF-8.

Thus:

```
const char bullet_utf8[] = "\xe2\x80\xa2";
gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor(textBuffer, bullet_utf8, strlen(bullet_utf8));
```

You can see the UTF-8 encoding of this character [here, for instance](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I translate u'\u2022' from Python to C?

If you are using c++ compiler to build it, and the compiler have spec c++0x or c++11 (you can specify with `g++ -std=c++0x`), you can write the code like following.

```
gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor(textbuffer, u8"\u2022", -1);
```